# Add subemenu option page

Tags: plugins, sub-menu

[image: "screenshot"]

How can I create a submenu page like this?
I have taken a look at add_menu_page and add_submenu_page, but I dont get further from there.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can use any option framework like option tree, redux framework, titan framework to easily create and customize your theme option. But If you want to create it manually than you can search and follow some tutorial like [This](https://blog.templatetoaster.com/wordpress-settings-api-creating-theme-options/)

Answer (score 0):

I am sure other people could point out other methods, but I'm just putting here what I consider to be the fastest method: use [Advanced Custom Fields PRO](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/pro/) and their [option pages functionality](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/options-page/). From their documentation:

```
if( function_exists('acf_add_options_page') ) {

acf_add_options_page(array(
    'page_title'    => 'Theme General Settings',
    'menu_title'    => 'Theme Settings',
    'menu_slug'     => 'theme-general-settings',
    'capability'    => 'edit_posts',
    'redirect'      => false
));

acf_add_options_sub_page(array(
    'page_title'    => 'Theme Header Settings',
    'menu_title'    => 'Header',
    'parent_slug'   => 'theme-general-settings',
));

acf_add_options_sub_page(array(
    'page_title'    => 'Theme Footer Settings',
    'menu_title'    => 'Footer',
    'parent_slug'   => 'theme-general-settings',
));

}
```

Then, when you need any of the values from the option pages, just use something like this:

```
$option_x = get_field('option_x', 'options');
```